# omniNames service won't start, but directly calling executable works

Tags: redhawksdr, omniorb

For some reason the omniNames service won't start (again), but if call the omniNames executable it starts without a problem. This problem seems to reoccur every once in a while.

Calling omniNames appears to start fine...

```
>> sudo /sbin/service omniNames start
Starting omniNames:                                        [  OK  ]
```

However, after checking on the status and listing naming service objects, it is apparent that omniNames did NOT successfully start:

```
>> sudo /sbin/service omniNames status
omniNames is stopped

>> nameclt list
Caught a TRANSIENT exception when trying to validate the type of the 
NamingContext. Is the naming service running?
```

If I try to directly call the omniNames executable and ask it to start on the same port, everything works fine.

```
>> sudo omniNames -start 2809

Fri Feb 14 18:48:35 2014:

Starting omniNames for the first time.
Wrote initial log file.
Read log file successfully.
Root context is IOR:010000002b00000049444c3a6f6d672e6f72672f436f734e616d696e672f4e616d696e67436f6e746578744578743a312e30000001000000000000006c000000010102000a00000031302e322e382e333500f90a0b0000004e616d6553657276696365000300000000000000080000000100000000545441010000001c00000001000000010001000100000001000105090101000100000009010100035454410800000053abfe5201001037
Checkpointing Phase 1: Prepare.
Checkpointing Phase 2: Commit.
Checkpointing completed.

>> nodeBooter -D
INFO:DomainManager - Starting Domain Manager
WARN:EventChannelSupport - Invalid Criteria for creating event channel REDHAWK_DEV.ODM_Channel
WARN:EventChannelSupport - Invalid Criteria for creating event channel REDHAWK_DEV.IDM_Channel
INFO:DomainManager - Starting ORB!


>> nameclt list
EventChannelFactory
REDHAWK_DEV/
```

I already tried deleting the logs, as suggested here: [Error When Starting OmniEvents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19968407/error-when-starting-omnievents)

For reference, I'm running Centos 6.4 x64. Also, the contents of /etc/omniORB.cfg is:

```
InitRef = NameService=corbaname::127.0.0.1:2809
supportBootstrapAgent = 1
InitRef = EventService=corbaloc::127.0.0.1:11169/omniEvents
```

Any idea what else could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As well as the files listed in the previous post that you referenced, you may need to delete files in /var/log/omniORB.

Delete the files named:

```
/var/log/omniORB/omninames-<computer_name>.bak
/var/log/omniORB/omninames-<computer_name>.log
```

Then try starting omniNames again and see if it starts properly.